# button inside a div wont display it's relative text

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-css-modules

I am working with ReactJS and I am creating a simple clickable button but here's the problem:
It wont show the written message on button when I place it inside a div.

Screenshot:
[image]

Code snippet:HTML

```css
.nm:hover {
  background-image: url(../assets/glitchnoise.jpg);
  text-shadow: -1px 0px 21px rgba(255,255,255,0.46);    
  background-size: 400% 400%;
    background-position: -100%;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
            background-clip: text;

            animation: animatedtext-slow .2s infinite alternate-reverse;
    transition: .8s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* Safari */
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Chrome */     
       -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
        -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
            user-select: none;
      }


      @keyframes animatedtext-slow {
        from {
           background-position: -100%;
        }
        to{
          background-position: -400%;
        }
      }


.btn-component{
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: center;
  
  
}
  
.btn{ 
width: 173px;
height: 47px;
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.93);
border: 1.5px solid #000000;
font-family: 'Maiden Orange';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 400;
font-size: 24px;


filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 4px #000000);
  }
```

```html
<div className='nm'> FLEXITY
        <div className='btn-component'>
          <button className='btn'>LISTEN NOW</button>
         </div>
        </div>
```

I do not understand why the text inside the button isn't displayed. While I tried to take the btn-component out, and it displays the content of button correctly i.e "LISTEN NOW".
I cannot take the btn-component out as it is a responsiveness issue if done so.

What else can I try?

Tech Stack: ReactJS

Comment: [Works for me](https://jsfiddle.net/uft3mzrb/).  Are you sure this is the *only* CSS being applied to the result?

Comment: I am using ReactJS, what can it be?

Comment: If the problem is the styling (and the question indicates that it is) then React is hardly relevant, aside from whatever code is used to *apply* styling.  In the browser you have HTML and CSS.  JavaScript code may modify those things, but the markup and the styling is what produces the visual result.  And the markup and styling shown does not produce the visual result indicated.  My only real guess at the moment is that you have more styling being applied than what's shown here.  You can use your browser's debugging tools to inspect elements and observe the styles applied to them.

Answer (score -1):

The problem was in the parent div:

at line:`-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;`

adding this to the box div: `-webkit-text-fill-color: black;` works